# Using the triangle inequality to prove a geometrical problem

Tags: geometry

> Let AD be the median of $\triangle ABC$  from the corner A. Show that
> $\dfrac{AB+AC-BC}2<AD<\dfrac{AB+AC}2$.

[image]

**My proposition**

Let us use the triangle inequality to study the first term of the inequality given in the question.

Consider $\triangle ABC$ , then we have by the triangle inequality

$$AB+AC\geq BC,$$
which means that:

$$AB+AC-BC\geq 0,$$
and

$$\dfrac{AB+AC-BC}{2}\geq 0$$
Hence we have the first term of the inequality is given by:
$$\dfrac{AB+AC-BC}2\geq 0$$

Consider now the third term in the inequality:

$$\frac{AB+AC}{2}.$$

Clearly the numerator differs by the numerator in
$\dfrac{AB+AC-BC}{2}\geq 0$ by the term $-BC$, hence:

$$AB+AC-BC< AB+AC,$$
$\forall BC>0$, so we can form the inequality:

$$\frac{AB+AC-BC}{2}<\frac{AB+BC}{2}$$

We now need to prove the latter, where $\frac{AB+AC-BC}{2}<AD<AB+BC$

The median forms two triangles out of  $\triangle{ABC}$ , which are  $\triangle{ABD}$ and $\triangle{ADC}$. We can therefore re-apply the triangle inequality on each of these two and obtain:

$$AB\leq AD+BD,$$
and
$$AC\leq AD+DC$$

Which gives that

$$AD\geq AB-BD$$

and

$$AD\geq AC-DC$$

Now, since the median $AD$ divides $BC$ at the center, then $BD=DC$, so we can form a single governing inequality for $AD$:

$$AD\geq AB-\frac{BC}{2},$$
which is
$$AD\geq\frac{2AB-BC}{2}$$

Now, \textbf{since we are considering an equiangular triangle we }have that $2AB=AB+AC$, so we can write

$$AD\geq\frac{AB+AC-BC}{2},$$

so we have proven the first part of the inequality:
$$\boxed{\frac{AB+AC-BC}{2}<AD}<\dfrac{AB+AC}2.$$

The last part is trivial, since $AB+AC-BC<AB+AC$, and $AD\leq AB$ we readily obtain that the following inequality holds:

$$\boxed{\frac{AB+AC-BC}{2}<AD<\dfrac{AB+AC}2},$$
by the argument of the triangle inequality.

However, the proof here is only valid for any triangle as shown in the image, where all sides are of equal length. However, the proof should be for all triangles such as right triangles too.

What is the correct approach here?

Any ideas welcomed,

Thanks

Comment: For the second inequality: extend the triangle to a parallelogram, so that AD is half of its diagonal. You will obtain a triangle with side lengths 2 AD, AB and AC.

Comment: For the first inequality, write in $\Delta ABD$, $\Delta ACD$ the inequalitiy between $AD$ and the difference of the other two sides. For instance $BC-BD<AD$. Add them...